# Jinja Template Sub Loop Optimization

Tags: python-2.7, flask, jinja2

I have the following loop using the Jinja template in a Flask project:

```
<select style="width: 125px;" id="ddlQuarters" name="ddlQuarters">
    {% for e in element_values if e.DataKey == 'Quarter' %}
        {% for v in e.DataElementValues | reverse %}
            <option value="{{ v.DataElementValueId }}">{{ v.Value }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Is there a way to optimize the jinja for loop so I don't need to do a sub loop to get the data elements that I want? Or, another question, would doing it in a single loop be any different as far as speed goes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually try to avoid nested loops like this in the template. I would do this in the controller/view, create a single list and send my list down to the template.

Of course your method is perfectly valid. Are you noticing performance/speed issues? if so you may want to consider implementing a caching strategy (if using Flask http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/) and cache just your loop directly inside the template. e.g - this will cache your loop for 5 mins:

```
{% cache 60*5 %}
<select style="width: 125px;" id="ddlQuarters" name="ddlQuarters">
    {% for e in element_values if e.DataKey == 'Quarter' %}
        {% for v in e.DataElementValues | reverse %}
            <option value="{{ v.DataElementValueId }}">{{ v.Value }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
{% endcache %}
```

If you decide to move your logic to the view (mentioned above), you could also cache the list before you push it down to the template.

g